# how to color td in table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to color the `td` in a table with a click function.

but it just color me the second `td` as you see in the picture.[image]

I try with code:

**jquery**

```
$(document).on('click', "#table_user tr:not(:first) td:first-child", function() {
$("#edit").addClass('selected');
});
```

**css:**

```
.selected {
 background-color: #ffd659;
}


<table id="table_user" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-checkable order-column">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th width="67%"> User </th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                  <tr id="edit">
                    <td>test test</td>
                    <td>
                      <a  title="Edit" class="btn btn-icon-only btn-outline blue"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"> </i></a>
                      <a  title="Delete" class="btn btn-icon-only btn-outline red" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> </i></a>

                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

Comment: if you want to color the `td` why are you targeting the `tr`?

Comment: share full code, you have for sure more CSS

Answer (score 0):

Because the targeted `td` is the last-child in the `table`, you can just use `#table_user td:last-of-type` as selector:

```
$(document).on('click', "#table_user td:last-of-type", function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Demo [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YeyNMG?editors=0010)..!

Answer (score -1):

Just use this to change all td color :

```
$("td").css("color","green");
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want every td to have background color when it is clicked, you can to this:

```
$(document).on('click', "#table_user  td", function() {   
     $(this).addClass('selected'); 
});
```